# how to filter products based on category

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

I'm creating an e-commerce website where I show 3 options "body lotion", "body wash" and "body scrub" the customer can click on any of these options, and the respective product shows up.

I have the products stored in the "U20Arr" and a "type" object key specifying whether it's of type body lotion or body wash or a body scrub

can somebody please help me on how do I filter out the products based on the category /type

the code of the same where at present I'm displaying all the products

```
import React from 'react'
import u20bg from "../assets/u20bg.png";
import "../styles/Under20.css";
import {
    Breadcrumb,
    BreadcrumbItem,
    BreadcrumbLink,
    BreadcrumbSeparator,
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { ChevronRightIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import filterBtn from "../assets/filterBtn.png";
import sortBtn from "../assets/sortBtn.png"
import { useState } from 'react';

const Under20 = () => {
    const [filter, SetFilter] = useState(false);

    const [sort, SetSort] = useState(false);

  

    const filterShowHandler = () => {
        SetFilter(!filter)

    }

    const toggleSortHandler = () => {
        SetSort(!sort)
    }


    var u20arr = [

        // body wash
        {
            id: "43",
            name: "NATURAL LEMON BODY WASH",
            price: 18,
            type: "bodywash",
            primaryImage: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NB_ScalpScrub200mlTube_200mL_02_large.jpg?v=1654006879",
            hoverImg: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NO_Lists_for_Site-SIG_3ec6e6c0-aee5-483d-a6c9-e4abab736fd7_large.png?v=1654006879",
            stars: 4,
            descr: "Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        "

        },

        {
            id: "44",
            name: "NATURAL STRAWBERRY BODY WASH",
            price: 15,
            type: "bodywash",
            primaryImage: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NB_Leave-InConditioner_250ml_02_large.jpg?v=1654006878",
            hoverImg: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NaturalBalance_7be6d9d2-0387-44f2-9949-b03a344fc044_large.jpg?v=1654006878",
            stars: 5,
            descr: "Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        "

        },


        {
            id: "45",
            name: "NATURAL STRAWBERRY BODY WASH",
            price: 11,
            type: "bodywash",
            primaryImage: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/TravelPack2019_large.jpg?v=1652797301",
            hoverImg: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/TravelPack2019_large.jpg?v=1652797301",
            stars: 5,
            descr: "Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        "

        },

        // body loption
        {
            id: "46",
            name: "NATURAL BLUEBERRY BODY LOTION",
            price: 15,
            type: "bodyLotion",
            primaryImage: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/CreamyBodyWash500ml_large.jpg?v=1649168513",
            hoverImg: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/CreamyBodyFinal_large.jpg?v=1649168513",
            stars: 5,
            descr: "Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        "

        },

        {
            id: "47",
            name: "NATURAL KIWI BODY LOTION",
            price: 19,
            type: "bodyLotion",
            primaryImage: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Biomarine_Facial_Serum_02_FOR_WEB_large.jpg?v=1646144556",
            hoverImg: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/MicrosoftTeams-image_5_-SMALL_large.jpg?v=1646144556",
            stars: 5,
            descr: "Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        "

        },

        {
            id: "48",
            name: "NATURAL AVACODA BODY LOTION",
            price: 14,
            type: "bodyLotion",
            primaryImage: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Hydra_Eye_Gel_15ml_Tube_02_FOR_WEB_large.jpg?v=1646144555",
            hoverImg: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/MicrosoftTeams-image_5_-SMALL_533a775e-6e81-48de-bafa-6250300a0219_large.jpg?v=1646144555",
            stars: 5,
            descr: "Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        "

        },

        //// bodyScrub

        {
            id: "49",
            name: "EXFOLIATING JELLY SCRUB",
            price: 19,
            type: "bodyScrub",
            primaryImage: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Brightening_JellyExfoliator125ml_02_large.jpg?v=1629210220",
            hoverImg: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NO_Lists_for_Site_BRIGHTENING_451cbd3f-1e8b-446a-a45e-61cc31826f69_large.jpg?v=1629210220",
            stars: 5,
            descr: "Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        "

        },

        {
            id: "50",
            name: "EXFOLIATING APPPLE SCRUB",
            price: 9,
            type: "bodyScrub",
            primaryImage: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Brightening_IlluminatingMoisturiser60ml_02_large.jpg?v=1629210218",
            hoverImg: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NO_Lists_for_Site_BRIGHTENING_cf1ff5a7-5a32-4bb0-a7ce-be69ccc9fcf0_large.jpg?v=1629210219",
            stars: 5,
            descr: "Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        "

        },

        {
            id: "51",
            name: "EXFOLIATING KIWI SCRUB",
            price: 16,
            type: "bodyScrub",
            primaryImage: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Bergamot_PachouliBodyWash500mL1000x1000x144_large.jpg?v=1637072534",
            hoverImg: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Bergamot_PachouliBodyWashpumpLifestyle1000x1000x144_large.jpg?v=1637072534",
            stars: 5,
            descr: "Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        "

        },

    ]



    return (
        <div className='u20MainParent'>
            <p className=' bg-white z-50 relative w100vw'>  </p>

            <div className='u20Hold'>
                <img src={u20bg} className="u20Pic" />
            </div>

            <div className='u20HeadingHold gap-20 justify-center relative flex flex-col'>
                <p className='u20Heading'> Under $20 </p>
                <p className='u20Desc'> Shop Sukin natural and vegan collection of skincare and hair care gifts under $20.</p>
            </div>

            <div className='u20BreadCrumbHold absolute text-sm'>
                <Breadcrumb spacing='8px' separator={<ChevronRightIcon />}>
                    <BreadcrumbItem>
                        <Link to={`/`}>Home</Link>
                    </BreadcrumbItem>


                    <BreadcrumbItem>
                        <Link to={`/`}>Under 20</Link>
                    </BreadcrumbItem>
                </Breadcrumb>
            </div>

            <div className='filterSortHold flex flex-row gap-8 absolute text-left'>

                <img src={filterBtn} className=" w-36 cursor-pointer scale" onClick={filterShowHandler} />

                <img src={sortBtn} className=" w-36 cursor-pointer scale" onClick={toggleSortHandler} />
            </div>

            <div className='filterOptionsHold  relative'>
                {filter && <div className='flex rounded-xl gap-8 flex-col boxSh fof absolute '>
                    <p className='ml-10 cursor-pointer'> Body Lotion</p>
                    <p className='ml-10 cursor-pointer'> Body Scrub </p>
                    <p className='ml-10 cursor-pointer text-white' > Body Wash </p>
                </div>}
            </div>

            <div>

                <div className='sortOptionsHold relative'>
                    {sort && <div className='flex rounded-xl flex-col gap-7 boxSh2 fof absolute'>

                        <p className='ml-20 cursor-pointer'> A - Z </p>
                        <p className='ml-20 cursor-pointer'> Z - A </p>
                        <p className='ml-10 cursor-pointer'> LOW TO HIGH </p>
                        <p className='ml-10 cursor-pointer text-white'> HIGH TO LOW </p>

                    </div>}
                </div>


            </div>

            <div className='flex gap-20 flex-wrap relative top-96 justify-center text-center'>
                {u20arr.map((item) => {
                    return (<div key={item.id}>
                        <img src={item.primaryImage} className="w-32" />
                        <p> ${item.price} </p>
                    </div>)
                })}
            </div>





        </div >


    )

}

export default Under20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filtering you can utilize `filter` function, something like this:

```js
const u20arr = [......];

const bodyLotionProducts = u20arr.filter(product => product.type === 'bodyLotion')
```

then you can use `bodyLotionProducts` in your JSX element

Comment: Hey there the solution is working perfectly. Thank you so much wish you a good day:)

Answer (score 1):

**To Avoid re-computation for the filtered element it is advisable to memorized the value** and to do that you used `useMemo` hook

```
...
const bodyLotionCategory = React.useMemo(()=> {
  u20arr.filter(({type}) => type === 'bodyLotion')
},[u20arr])
...
```

Comment: While this answer is a good advice, it is not an answer to the given question. This should rather be a comment on another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74474065/12320578

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about a reduce?

```js
// useMemo will avoid filtering it several times
const u20GroupedByType = useMemo(() => u20arr
  .reduce((acc, current) => {
    // ||= set the value only if acc[current.type] is not defined
    acc[current.type] ||= []
    acc[current.type].push(current)
    return acc
  }, {}), [u20arr])
```

And the result looks like:

```js
{
  bodywash: [
    {
      id: '43',
      name: 'NATURAL LEMON BODY WASH',
      price: 18,
      type: 'bodywash',
      primaryImage: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NB_ScalpScrub200mlTube_200mL_02_large.jpg?v=1654006879',
      hoverImg: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NO_Lists_for_Site-SIG_3ec6e6c0-aee5-483d-a6c9-e4abab736fd7_large.png?v=1654006879',
      stars: 4,
      descr: 'Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        '
    },
    {
      id: '44',
      name: 'NATURAL STRAWBERRY BODY WASH',
      price: 15,
      type: 'bodywash',
      primaryImage: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NB_Leave-InConditioner_250ml_02_large.jpg?v=1654006878',
      hoverImg: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NaturalBalance_7be6d9d2-0387-44f2-9949-b03a344fc044_large.jpg?v=1654006878',
      stars: 5,
      descr: 'Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        '
    },
    {
      id: '45',
      name: 'NATURAL STRAWBERRY BODY WASH',
      price: 11,
      type: 'bodywash',
      primaryImage: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/TravelPack2019_large.jpg?v=1652797301',
      hoverImg: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/TravelPack2019_large.jpg?v=1652797301',
      stars: 5,
      descr: 'Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        '
    }
  ],
  bodyLotion: [
    {
      id: '46',
      name: 'NATURAL BLUEBERRY BODY LOTION',
      price: 15,
      type: 'bodyLotion',
      primaryImage: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/CreamyBodyWash500ml_large.jpg?v=1649168513',
      hoverImg: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/CreamyBodyFinal_large.jpg?v=1649168513',
      stars: 5,
      descr: 'Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        '
    },
    {
      id: '47',
      name: 'NATURAL KIWI BODY LOTION',
      price: 19,
      type: 'bodyLotion',
      primaryImage: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Biomarine_Facial_Serum_02_FOR_WEB_large.jpg?v=1646144556',
      hoverImg: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/MicrosoftTeams-image_5_-SMALL_large.jpg?v=1646144556',
      stars: 5,
      descr: 'Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        '
    },
    {
      id: '48',
      name: 'NATURAL AVACODA BODY LOTION',
      price: 14,
      type: 'bodyLotion',
      primaryImage: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Hydra_Eye_Gel_15ml_Tube_02_FOR_WEB_large.jpg?v=1646144555',
      hoverImg: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/MicrosoftTeams-image_5_-SMALL_533a775e-6e81-48de-bafa-6250300a0219_large.jpg?v=1646144555',
      stars: 5,
      descr: 'Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        '
    }
  ],
  bodyScrub: [
    {
      id: '49',
      name: 'EXFOLIATING JELLY SCRUB',
      price: 19,
      type: 'bodyScrub',
      primaryImage: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Brightening_JellyExfoliator125ml_02_large.jpg?v=1629210220',
      hoverImg: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NO_Lists_for_Site_BRIGHTENING_451cbd3f-1e8b-446a-a45e-61cc31826f69_large.jpg?v=1629210220',
      stars: 5,
      descr: 'Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        '
    },
    {
      id: '50',
      name: 'EXFOLIATING APPPLE SCRUB',
      price: 9,
      type: 'bodyScrub',
      primaryImage: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Brightening_IlluminatingMoisturiser60ml_02_large.jpg?v=1629210218',
      hoverImg: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/NO_Lists_for_Site_BRIGHTENING_cf1ff5a7-5a32-4bb0-a7ce-be69ccc9fcf0_large.jpg?v=1629210219',
      stars: 5,
      descr: 'Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        '
    },
    {
      id: '51',
      name: 'EXFOLIATING KIWI SCRUB',
      price: 16,
      type: 'bodyScrub',
      primaryImage: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Bergamot_PachouliBodyWash500mL1000x1000x144_large.jpg?v=1637072534',
      hoverImg: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0081/7374/8305/products/Bergamot_PachouliBodyWashpumpLifestyle1000x1000x144_large.jpg?v=1637072534',
      stars: 5,
      descr: 'Our Scalp Scrub removes product build up and impurities with a refreshing blend of Peppermint & Ginger Extract.        '
    }
  ]
}
```